# Multiple .order() calls using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can you specify multiple .order() calls when doing a query in Google App Engine to get a subset sorting?  You can do this in GQL, so I assumed you could do it as .order() calls, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
q = Score.all()
q.filter("level = ", level)
q.order("-score")
q.order("-submitted")
scoreList = q.fetch(10)
```

This would sort high scores of equal value to the most recent on top.

Comment: Could you clarify "it doesn't seem to be working". What do you expect to get and what do you get?

Comment: The above example is simplified.  I would except to get a list of the top 10 scores sorted by 'score' then those sorted by 'submitted' within each 'score' sorting.  So, if there were two scores of the same value, the newest one would be first.  If there were 100 scores of the same value, I'd get the 10 newest.  Is this expected to work?  If it is then I'll start looking at other places in my code.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have been doing this in my code with the expected result. I was wondering if the indexes are not up to date. Have you added the relevant index after you already had data in the datastore?

Comment: BTW, is this a production or SDK issue?

Comment: I've tested it here (1.6.2, Python 2.7, OSX 10.7) and it worked as expected. I chained order methods, but, as gae123 pointed out (and thus enlightened me), your code should work too.

But now that we are in the weird territory, what version of Python and SDK are you running on what platform?

Comment: OK, I looked into this a little deeper and I think there is a bug in my code somewhere else.  As I mentioned, my example is much simplified.  Thanks all.

Comment: Yeah, this is not working.  It mostly works, but fails every so often. I wonder if it's related to the way GAE stores data and the shards (or whatever they call them).

Comment: Can you check if the code I'll post in the anwer below works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Roger, try this on your dev environment and see if it works:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext import db


class Score(db.Model):
    level = db.IntegerProperty()
    score = db.IntegerProperty()
    submitted = db.IntegerProperty()


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        level = 1
        if Score.all().count() == 0:
            Score(level = 1, score = 10, submitted = 10).put()
            Score(level = 1, score = 10, submitted = 11).put()
            Score(level = 1, score = 10, submitted = 12).put()
            Score(level = 1, score = 11, submitted = 10).put()
            Score(level = 1, score = 11, submitted = 20).put()
            Score(level = 1, score = 12, submitted = 10).put()

        q = Score.all().filter("level = ", level).order("-score").order("-submitted")
        score_list = q.fetch(10)
        self.response.out.write([
                (s.level, s.score, s.submitted) for s in score_list ])


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```